# Extracting a Variable Number of Letters from a Formula using VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel foumala such as =+'Haver-in'!$B$. I would like to be able to only extract the letter, 'B' in this example. I can do this using Mid. However, I have additional formulas for other columns, such as =+'Haver-in'!$AB$. How can I use VBA to only extract the letters? Thanks.

The column contains six formulas that can be different. For example, the first formula is =+'Haver-in'!$B$1233 and the third is =+ROUND('Haver-in'!$N$1233*100,1), and so on. I would like to be able to loop through the column and increase the 1233 by one while the rest of the formula stays the same.

Comment: How would you like to be returned the letters for a specific column? In the next column, would it be OK?

Comment: `Evaluate("='Haver-in'!$B$6").Column` would return 2.... numerics are easier to work with than the column letter.  Leaving the `+` sign in gives an Object Required error though - you don't need the + sign (isn't that a throwback to Lotus 123?).

Answer (score 3):

Please, try the next function:

```
Function extractLetter(rng As Range) As String
    extractLetter = Split(Split(rng.Formula, "!$")(1), "$")(0)
End Function
```

It can be tested using such a way:

```
Sub testExtrLetter()
   Debug.Print extractLetter(ActiveCell)
End Sub
```

You can use the next fast way to process a column and return in the next one:

```
Sub extractAllLetters()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrFin, i As Long
  Const colLett As String = "G" 'use here the letter of the column to be processed
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range(colLett & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in the processed column
  
  ReDim arrFin(1 To lastR, 1 To 1) 'ReDim the array to receive the processed result
  For i = 1 To lastR
        arrFin(i, 1) = extractLetter(sh.cells(i, colLett))
  Next i
  
  'Drop the final array (arrFin) content, at once:
  sh.Range(colLett & 1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub
```

Comment: That solution works. I can loop though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ectrimm I will also post a fast method, using an array...

Comment: @ectrimm Should I understand that the above answer does not answer your question, as it was formulated? Even without the global sub processing the whole column...

Comment: @FaneDuru what does the `(1)` and `(0)` mean in the line `Split(Split(rng.Formula, "!$")(1), "$")(0)`?

Comment: @k1dr0ck `Split` creates an array using `!$` as separator. `(1) means the second array element (array is 1D type, zero based). Then, it splits it by `$' and extracts its first element `(0)`, which is the necessary letter.

Comment: I did not do a very good job of explaining what I needed. Is there a way to essentially increase the number in the formula by one? For example, if the formula is =+ROUND('Haver-in'!$BG$1228*100,1), and I need the 1228 to increase to 1229. The formulas are similar on each line, but they are different. For example, another example is =+'Haver-in'!$B$1229. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For a formula, try:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(FORMULATEXT(cell_ref),"$"),"$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy these formula's

[image]

In field `D6` you should find a letter B

NOTE:

- It it possible in Excel2013 to show formulas using CTRL+`
- It is unknown, to me, if this option still works on other versions of Excel.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to be able to loop through all of the columns that contain a formula and extract the letters. Is it possible to do in VBA?

Comment: You can combine those 5 formula's that I gave in column D to one formula.  But looping through all of the columns, seems to be a job for a macro. What do you want to do with these found letters (which obviously should have been part of your question) ?

Comment: For versions Excel for Microsoft 365 Excel for the web Excel 2021 Excel 2019 Excel 2016 Excel 2013 Excel 2010 Excel 2007 it should be Ctrl+` (grave accent) - see [Support MS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-or-hide-formulas-f7f5ab4e-bf24-4efc-8fc9-0c1b77a5356f)